# Adding network service user to Admin group

Tags: c#

I am getting null in the user variable ..what am I missing????

```
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
GroupPrincipal user = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, @"NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE");
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "Administrators");
group.Members.Add(user);
group.Save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Speculating here, but maybe because [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> The NetworkService account is a predefined local account used by the
>   service control manager. This account is not recognized by the
>   security subsystem

Also, I'm not sure adding the Network Service account to the Admin group is a good thing to be doing from a security point of view, even if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The LSA Accounts (`NT AUTHORITY\...`) can **NOT** be looked up by name or sAMAccountName, but **can** be looked up by SID:

```cs
var account = new NTAccount(@"NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE")
  .Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));

using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
{
  var user = GroupPrincipal.
    FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.Sid, account.Value);
  var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "Administrators");
  group.Members.Add(user);
}
group.Save();
```